# What action should be taken with the ".live" tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, tag-block-request

There are currently 51 posts in the [.live](/questions/tagged/.live) tag, which all refer to the `jQuery` `live` function.
There's a better tag for that function: [jquery-live](/questions/tagged/jquery-live) with 322 posts. I thought to suggest `.live`  as a  synonym, but it sounds like an awful tag name, maybe all the question should be migrated to `jquery-live` and close the `.live` tag?

What action should be taken with the ".live" tag?

Comment: If you suggest it as a synonym and it get accepted, then the tag will automatically be migrated.

Comment: @Chichiray. But I don't think `.live` is a valid name for a tag. just like `round` isn't `.round`...

Comment: Just manually retag them all to [jquery-live]. @Chichiray: Existing questions aren't automatically migrated just because a synonym is created. It has to be done manually.

Comment: @animuson: oh, if that's true, that would be rather strange. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [.live](/questions/tagged/.live) tag is just as ambiguous as the [live](/questions/tagged/live) tag, which should also be taken care of at some point. For now, the [.live](/questions/tagged/.live) tag will go away in around 24 hours. Since it had such a low question count, I doubt a blacklist is necessary since there's really no evidence that it will reappear.